# How to capture two audio sources on separate tracks with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I'm currently using the following FFmpeg command to record my screen and two audio sources:

```
"C:\FFmpeg\ffmpeg" -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
-c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -crf 26 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -y "C:\FFmpeg\output.mp4"
```

It works, but it mixes my two audio sources, microphone and virtual-audio-capturer, into a single audio track.

How can I capture the same audio sources but instead of mixing them into one track, save two, separate audio tracks instead? The resulting MP4 file would contain the video track, audio track 1 (virtual-audio-capturer) and audio track 2 (microphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the filters and map all inputs.

```
"C:\FFmpeg\ffmpeg" -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Logitech USB Headset)" -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 
-c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -crf 26 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -y "C:\FFmpeg\output.mp4"
```